# How to flip a DialogFragment

Tags: android, dialogfragment

[image]

I am trying to do this animation in dialogFragment please help me how to do this.

I am using Fragment and attached a DialogFragment to this Fragment.

Below code (for flip animation) is working fine for Fragment, but it is not working for DialogFragment,I have seen that `DialogFragment` is extend by Fragment. Any Help expected.
And using this library.

```
compile 'com.labo.kaji:fragmentanimations:0.1.1'



@Override
    public Animation onCreateAnimation(int transit, boolean enter, int nextAnim) {
        return FlipAnimation.create(FlipAnimation.LEFT, enter, 600);
}
```

Comment: cretaed a dialog fragment? add animation to that as style thats it

Comment: I have posted an image for the animation, how can i do this for dialogfragments, please help me.

Comment: Try with xml animation it works

Comment: Please provide me the code